# nhibernate Foreign key must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am using NHibernate 3.3 with FluentNHibernate 1.3.

My database has two tables: InvoiceHeader and InvoiceDetail.  The header has a composite key of two columns.  The detail has a single column primary key.  The problem is that the detail does not have both parts of the composite key; it only has one part of it.  No foreign key constraints exist.

```
public class TInvoiceHeader 
{
    public virtual TInvoiceHeaderIdentifier Identifier { get; set; }
    public virtual long Dwinvoiceid { get; set; }
    public virtual int InvTimeID { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<TInvoiceDetail> Details { get; set; }
    ....
}

public class TInvoiceHeaderIdentifier
{
    public virtual long Dwinvoiceid { get; set; }
    public virtual int InvTimeID { get; set; }
    ....
}

public TInvoiceHeaderMap() 
{
    CompositeId<TInvoiceHeaderIdentifier>(x => x.Identifier)
        .KeyProperty(x => x.Dwinvoiceid, "DWInvoiceID")
        .KeyProperty(x => x.InvTimeID, "InvTimeID");
    HasMany<TInvoiceDetail>(x => x.Details).KeyColumn("DWInvoiceID");
    ....
}

public class TInvoiceDetail 
{
    public virtual TInvoiceHeader Header { get; set; }
    public virtual long Dwinvoicedetailid { get; set; }
    public virtual long Dwinvoiceid { get; set; }
    ....
}

public TInvoiceDetailMap() 
{
    Table("tInvoiceDetail");
    LazyLoad();
    Id(x => x.Dwinvoicedetailid).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("DWInvoiceDetailId");
    References<TInvoiceHeader>(x => x.Dwinvoiceid);
    ....
}
```

I have no idea how to make this work since the detail row doesn't have the InvTimeID key.  I'm getting:

> NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration - Foreign key (FKAD4039AB666D3F7:tInvoiceDetail [DWInvoiceID])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (tInvoiceHeader [DWInvoiceID, InvTimeID])
>   NHibernate.FKUnmatchingColumnsException: Foreign key (FKAD4039AB666D3F7:tInvoiceDetail [DWInvoiceID])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (tInvoiceHeader [DWInvoiceID, InvTimeID])
>      at NHibernate.Mapping.ForeignKey.AlignColumns(Table referencedTable)
>      at NHibernate.Mapping.ForeignKey.AlignColumns()
>      at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.SecondPassCompileForeignKeys(Table table, ISet done)
>   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration - Foreign key (FKAD4039AB666D3F7:tInvoiceDetail [DWInvoiceID])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (tInvoiceHeader [DWInvoiceID, InvTimeID])
>   NHibernate.FKUnmatchingColumnsException: Foreign key (FKAD4039AB666D3F7:tInvoiceDetail [DWInvoiceID])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (tInvoiceHeader [DWInvoiceID, InvTimeID])
>      at NHibernate.Mapping.ForeignKey.AlignColumns(Table referencedTable)
>      at NHibernate.Mapping.ForeignKey.AlignColumns()
>      at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.SecondPassCompileForeignKeys(Table table, ISet done)

Can this work?  My queries will always be going from header-to-detail, not vice versa.  I cannot modify the tables.

Comment: If two invoices can have the same invoice ID, how could this possibly work? Not just with NHibernate, but at all?

Comment: The header has a composite key.  The detail row has its own key.  Two headers can have the same DWInvoiceID, but they must then have different InvTimeIDs.

Comment: What hvd said. There is no way to establish a declarative fk relationship between two tables when the parent table has a composite primary key and the child table lacks one or more of the columns that comprise that key. Refactor the InvoiceHeader table.

Comment: @Amy But if two invoices both have invoice ID 1, how do you figure out which detail rows belong to the first of those invoices, and which belong to the second?

Comment: @Amy, your InvoiceHeader table design is wack.

Comment: Not my design.  I just started here.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue after upgrading nHibernate and Fluent nHibernate. It looked like it was getting confused with the column names.

The solution was to manually name my columns and the issue went away.

```
public void Override(AutoMapping<Record> mapping)
    {
        mapping.Id(x => x.Id).Column("RecordId");
        mapping.Map(x => x.Name).Not.Nullable();
        mapping.References(x => x.Parent).Not.Nullable().Column("ParentRecordId");
        mapping.References(x => x.Type).Not.Nullable().Column("TypeId");
    }
```